# Mapping between Model, View and Controller in PHP MVC implementation

Tags: php, model-view-controller, content-management-system, datamapper

Overview: I am building a CMS using PHP, and I am trying to implement this using MVC. I am trying to extend my code using [this structure](http://r.je/mvc2.phps), as it represents an accurate representation of MVC and it is quite straightforward. To communicate with my database I use Domain Objects and Data Mappers.

Questions:

- Is it really necessary to have a 1:1:1 mapping between a model, a view, and a controller?

> Example: For a blog system, when displaying a blog entry page I would create a controller called DisplayEntryController, and a View called DisplayEntryView. The view would get its information from the BlogMapper class (which communicates with the DB to retrieve the current blog entry) and a CommentMapper class (which communicates with the DB to retrieve the comments for the current blog entry). Is this good practice, considering that view works with 2 model objects? If not what is the alternative? If yes, how can this be implemented in a generic way?

- Can multiple controllers handle one page? For the example above, would it be possible to have a DisplayEntryController and a CommentController handling the relevant parts of a page displaying the blog entry? If yes, how would the 2 controllers coordinate?

Thank you in advance. Examples will be greatly appreciated.

---

Most PHP MVC implementations I've seen on the web use the page approach to organise their MVC. E.g. for the Home page, you have one view, one controller and one model. Routing for 1:1:1 mapping in MVC is straightforward, as you can enforce the location and naming of your MVC components, and when a request for the Home page comes it automatically looks for the following classes: HomeView HomeController and HomeModel.

This obviously doesn't work well in larger projects. How should routing be handled to support routing to multiple models (DataMappers), multiple views, without creating an overcomplicated router or adding a complex dependency injection layer?

> Example: As discussed above, when displaying a blog entry you display
>   the blog entry code and the comment section. To achieve this, it
>   communicates with two DataMappers, the one which gets the blog entry,
>   and the one which returns the comments for the blog. How can the view
>   be assigned to work with these two datamappers to get the data from
>   the DB?

Comment: No, having a 1:1:1 mapping between MVC parts would actually be wrong, since those "parts" are not even in same "weight group". Model is a layer, while controllers and views are classes. And multiple controllers *can* be reachable from same page, but I have no idea what you mean by "coordinate".

Comment: Routing for 1:1:1 mapping in MVC is straightforward, as you can enforce the location and naming of your MVC components, and when a request for the Home page comes it automatically looks for the following classes: HomeView HomeController and HomeModel. 
How do you handle routing when the view communicates with multiple models (DataMappers), without adding a complex dependency injection layer?

Comment: Example: As discussed above, when displaying a blog entry you display the blog entry code and the comment section. To achieve this, it communicates with two DataMappers, the one which gets the blog entry, and the one which returns the comments for the blog. How can the view be assigned to work with these two datamappers to get the data from the DB?

Comment: @Constantin, Add your comments as an answer.

Comment: @crafter why would you tell someone to add his additional question as an **answer**?!?!

Comment: @tereško, because I believe the response was of a quality that directly contributes to the original post. The comments are meant as additional follow up discussion around the post. It works both ways, but I believe answers are more prominent in questions, hence you can format them and they are not hidden.

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement to have a 1:1 mapping of the model, controller and view.

MVC works of a concept of a tiered approach to handling your application, with each tier being handled by 'agents' to implement the way they see fit. To explain this further, consider the following scenario.

Assume you process data, then hand them over to someone to store. You don't care where they store it and how they store the data, as long as the information is available again when you need it. You can happily go about processing your data, and then say to them for example 'This is project data for Client X, store it,' and later say 'Can you give me the project data for Client X.'

SO MVC works on this approach, whether the data storage guys dump all data together or pack them away is not important to you. However, what is important is the interface between the two parties when sending and retrieving. For example, you could decide to store the information as either *Client* data, or *Project* Data, or both.

Likewise, you could have agents collecting data and handling it to you to process. You don't care how many interfaces they use (for example, phone, web, email, mobile devices), but you care about what data they hand you. (Of course a rule might dictate that only web information must be handled). So the interfaces for collecting data might be different.

Therefore, each agent can use the most efficient method (and even combine or split them) to get the system working in their side, and therefore there is no mapping of the data.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. However, most PHP MVC implementations I've seen on the web use the page approach to organise their MVC. E.g. for the Home page, you have one view, one controller and one model. This obviously doesn't work well in larger projects.
How should routing be handled (in 1:1:1 mapping it's easy as it is uses the page name to find the HomeModel HomeController and HomeView) to support routing to multiple models, multiple views, without creating an overcomplicated router?

Comment: Correct observation. I recommend using a business object based approach. This is usually represented by a data table (for example Order). However, it should be the basis for your controller. Ask yourself "What business functions are allowed." The answers to this will form the Controller actions (Add, Delete, Print, Search, etc), and will indicate the views (eg order page), and models (eg, order, order item, products).